# How do I validate a password in eXist-db 2.2 via the XMLDB-embedded java API?

Tags: java, exist-db

I am updating an [eXist-db](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/homepage/index.html) XMLDB-embedded application from *v1.4* to *v2.2 (using Java 1.8)*.

The `user.validate(password)` method has been removed in v2.2.

Has it been moved or renamed to another class ?

Comment: formatting and slightly rephrased for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you could just attempt a login or retrieval of `/db` as that user, if it succeeds then you have the correct username/password, if not then you don't